# Printing a multiline string in one line for multiple times

Tags: python, string, printing, multiline

I have a multiline string like this.

```
""" Hello
    world """
```

I want to print this string for example 2 times but I want these two similar strings to be beside each other. Like this:

```
Hello    Hello
world    world
```

Can u guys help me?

Comment: You are sending your output to the console, which a line-oriented device, in other words it accepts and displays one line at a time. So there is no automatic way to do what you want. You need to decompose your data into separate lines, then assemble the lines and print them one by one.  There are libraries that will do this for you, for example PrettyTable : https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

Answer (score 0):

```
text = """ Hello
world """
_str = ''
for word in text :

    if word =='\n':
        word = ' '
        _str +=word
    else:
        _str+=word
    
print (_str)
```

output : Hello World

Comment: I don't think this output matches the desired output presented in OP's question.